# envio de datos jSOn por Ajax a Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, python-2.7

pueden ayudarme a leer los datos pasados desde AJAX a la view de django, tengo estos datos:

```
datos[] "[{\"nombre\":\"Test\",\"descripcion\":\"Test\",\"tipo\":\"L\",\"hora_inicial\":\"00:00\",\"hora_final\":\"23:59\",\"cantidad_pacientes\":\"200\",\"dias\":\"Lunes;Martes;Miercoles;\"},
{\"nombre\":\"Test2\",\"descripcion\":\"Test 2\",\"tipo\":\"L\",\"hora_inicial\":\"00:00\",\"hora_final\":\"23:59\",\"cantidad_pacientes\":\"100\",\"dias\":\"Lunes;Martes;Miercoles;Sabado;\"}]"
```

Como los interpreto en django?. Estoy intentando de esta manera:

```
datos = json.loads(request.POST.getlist('datos[]'))
data = request.POST.get('datos')
```

Mi función AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/agendas/parametrizar_laboratorio/',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data : {'datos[]':JSON.stringify(datos),csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 'True'){
                document.getElementById("frmCita").reset();
                $(".fileRemov").remove();
                mostrar("mensajeRegistro");
                location.href = ('/laboratorio/consultar_ordenes');
                lista_examenes = []
                idsExamenesTmp = []
            }
            else{
                console.log("False desde el backend");
            }
        }
    });
```

Pero me sale error

**expected string or buffer**

Python 2.7.

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale?

Comment: @Triby expected string or buffer  Ese error.